# Добавление в Object элементов

Tags: массивы, java

Есть код на `java`

```
Object[] param = {1,2,3,4};
Array array = connection.createArrayOf("integer", param);
CallableStatement proc = connection.prepareCall("{ call net_trains(?, ?) }");

proc.setArray(1, array);
proc.setInt(2, Ids.get(k))
proc.execute();
```

Вместо непосредственной инициализации массива Object хотелось бы иметь возможность заполнить его любым количестов элементов из

```
ArrayList<String> ProcessedTherms = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Каким образом это сделать?

Comment: а в чем проблема? получить элементы из ProcessedTherms или создать массив?

Comment: @G1yyk как добавить произвольное число элементов из

    ArrayList<String> ProcessedTherms = new ArrayList<String>();
в массив Object (скорее всего по программе количество элементов в этом массиве будет заранее определено через переменную `countofparams`, но также интересен случай неопределенной размерности массива `Object`)?

Answer (score 1):

Создайте список и преобразуйте его в массив методом [List.toArray](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28%29)

Comment: @a_gura мне нужно именно элементы ArrayList-а добавить в массив Object,  а не списка, или вы подразумевали, что в созданный список надо добавить элементы ArrayList-а (я не знаю, как это сделать), а затем преобразовать инициализированный список в массив методом `List.toArray` ?

Comment: @ivan89 А что такое по вашему ArrayList, если не список?

Answer (score 0):

Если тебе нужны не все элементы из `ArrayList<String> ProcessedTherms`, тогда придется создать еще один массив (`ArrayList<String> frame`), в который ты будешь сгружать нужные элементы, а потом тебе останется только инициализировать `Object[] obj = new Object[frame.size];` и забить элементами.

Вроде как-то так.

Comment: subList возвращает List, а не Object[].

Comment: Спасибо что поправил, я мельком глянул docs. Теперь буду иметь ввиду, на будущие пишите хоть за что минусуете )